# Is there a way to turn off LibreOfficeUpdate via terminal?

Tags: terminal, ssh, libreoffice, auto-update

Good morning everyone. I administrate few MacBook laptops (in remote locations). We control the versions of software that we allow users to use for compatibility issues. But end users nag as to install updates because of pop-ups. **As i cannot disable update mechanism via GUI I'd like to know if there is a way to do it remotely via terminal/ssh?** Or just remove the annoying pop up from taskbar.

Every laptop is using Mac OS 10.9.1 or 10.9.2. 
Thanks in advance for your advices

Answer (score 1):

You could try blocking all outgoing traffic of the application with the firewall (ipfw) or you can edit the hosts file in /etc/hosts to route the update server to localhost (127.0.0.1)

I don't know the specific update servers, but that would be not that hard to find out.

(for exampple here : update.services.openoffice.org -- so there should be a possible way. Be careful though because libreoffice/openOffice sometimes produce the error "The host name ... could not be resolved.")

Try also experimenting with the GUI on your Mac and the logfiles or list of open files (lsof)